# redirection between two pages Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

I have a asp.net form with several text boxes and a link-button which is redirected to the other page. here is my form:

```
<table>
<tr>
       <td >
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Name" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
       </td>

       <td> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_FatherName" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
       <td> 
       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_BirthPlace" runat="server"  OnClick="LinkButton_BirthPlace_Click"  >Search</asp:LinkButton>    </td> 
     </tr>
```

and it is my method for link button :

```
  protected void LinkButton_BirthPlace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect("~/Profile/CitySearch.aspx");
    }
```

my problem is: When I enter value in my text boxes and then click on link button , redirected to CitySearch.aspx page and when I come back to base page my values in text boxes were deleted.I need those values that I enterned.
What should I do?

Comment: where is your textboxes ???

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: I'm sorry,I edited it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to repopulate your textboxes with your information from the Session. Put a method similar to this on your "base page"

Psuedocode:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Birthplace = Session["Birthplace"].ToString();
        MyBirthplaceTextBox.Text = Birthplace;
    }
```

You'll need multiple Session values to store multiple pieces of information. You'll also want to code in some checks to make sure your session variables aren't null, and take action accordingly.

Comment: what is session["search"]? my text boxes are in base page and I enter value but when i click on link button and redirected to new page and come back from that page to base page I see that my value of text boxes were deleted and they have not any value and I must enter again.

Comment: You need to assign a value to Session["search"] in order to save the values from your first form. I suggest you read up on it, your initial question made it seem as if you understood Session objects. This will make a lot more sense if you learn about them instead of asking for a complete working example objects.http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try like This on your First Page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["search"]!=null)
            {

                TextBox_Name.Text = Session["search"].ToString();
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: where enter value to session["search"]?in CitySearch.aspx page?I enter value to text boxes in base page

Comment: when you press back button the page which will be displayed on that page you have to write this code

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack==false)
    {
        if (Session["search"]!=null)
        {

            TextBox_Name.Text = Session["search"].ToString();
        }

    }

}   
protected void LinkButton_BirthPlace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["search"] = TextBox_Name.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/Profile/CitySearch.aspx");
}
```